# c++ char c[256] in getLine

Tags: c++

Im viewing some old code that has no comments which I try to understand, the code:

```
std::vector<std::string> CardFactory::readFile(std::string fileName)
{
    std::vector<std::string> returnVal;
    std::ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open(fileName);
    if (myFile.is_open())
    {
        std::vector<string> textLines;
        char c[256];
        //not sure why the line below this is not in the while loop
        myFile.getline(c, 256);
        while (myFile.good()) {
            string line = string(c);
            textLines.push_back(line);
            myFile.getline(c, 256);
        }
        myFile.close();
        return textLines;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File not open " << std::endl;
        return std::vector<string>();
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

It returns a vector with lines of text. I understand all the code except the part where char c is used and the value 256.

```
char c[256];
```

and

```
myFile.getline(c, 256);
```

What is the purpose of the value 256?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline _Parameters: s - pointer to the character string to store the characters to. count - size of character string pointed to by s_

Comment: The buffersize, the amount allowed to be read.

Comment: Ever hear of a c style string?

Comment: Note: that line is not in the `while` loop because this is a typical case of "loop-and-a-half", and people prefer copy-pasting code rather than using `break` or `goto`.

Comment: @NathanOliver just now, if i understnad correctly an array of chars. And 256 in myFile.getline(c, 256); is the limit to reading?

Comment: @Quentin I ment wouldnt it be logical to start with the myFile.getline(c, 256); in the loop. the last loop will readLine and not push it.

Comment: much better would be `myFile.getline(c, sizeof(c));`

Comment: When downvoating please elaborate so i can improve the question.

Comment: Yep.  That is how people get input before they learn about `std::string` which is dynamic and allows you take in as much input as the user wants to supply.

Comment: @Quentin A for loop might have done the trick as well.

Comment: @BitTickler as long as the "half" is small enough to be crammed into the `for` condition, yes. It is indeed the case here.

Comment: @Quentin ``for(...; myFile.good(); ... )``

Comment: @BitTickler that would be `for(char c[256]; myFile.getline(c, 256), myFile.good();)`. Still readable enough.

Comment: @Quentin rather ``for(myFile.getLine(c,256);myFile.good();myFile.getLine(c,256))``

Comment: @BitTickler the goal is to avoid copy-pasting the code. A "loop-and-a-half" is that common pattern when a loop has to make half an iteration at its beginning or end -- copy-pasting that half is as bad a solution as copy-pasting always is.

Comment: `getline` returns the stream object so you could just write:`while (myFile.getline(c, 256).good())`

Comment: @Ferruccio why .good()? C++ read loops since the dawn of time directly test the stream: `while(myFile.getline(...))`

Comment: @Cubbi - I've always done that too, but I was trying to avoid making any unwarranted assumptions. The returned stream is implicitly convertible to `bool` but if you look at the table at the bottom of this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool `good()` does not behave exactly like `operator bool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) explains everything that you need to know. We can read that the parameters are:

> **Parameters**
>
> s -   pointer to the character string to store the characters to
>
> count -   size of character string pointed to by s

and we can also read:

> [...] extracts characters from *this and stores them in successive locations
> of the array whose first element is pointed to by s, until any of the
> following occurs (tested in the order shown):
>
> [...]
>
> - count-1 characters have been extracted (in which case
>   setstate(failbit) is executed).

So, the second argument is used to make sure that `getline` doesn't try to read  and insert more than 255 characters into your buffer `c`. Inserting more than 255 characters will result in undefined behavior.